# Write a C / C++ Polyglot

Tags: popularity-contest, c, c++, polyglot

This challenge's concept is pretty simple. All you have to do is write a program that will compile as both valid C and valid C++! Well, there are some catches. **The program must behave differently when compiled in each language.** The program must have different output for each language in order to be considered "behaving differently".

### Rules

- The program must be both valid C and C++
- The program must have different outputs based on the language it was compiled in.
- `#ifdef __cplusplus` or other "easy" preprocessor tricks are discouraged! (Other preprocessor operations are perfectly fine, though.)
- Try not to make it look completely obvious that the program does something different.

This is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so whoever has the most interesting and surprising solution wins. Have fun!

### Example:

I created my own program to see if this was even possible to do with out `#ifdef` tricks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *m="C++ rules!";

int t[11]={0,0,0,0,1,-1,-3,9,-8,82,0};

char tr(char c,int i)
{
    return c+((sizeof('!')+1)&1)*t[i];
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    for(;i<strlen(m);i++)
    {
        printf("%c",tr(m[i],i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This program outputs `C++ rules!` when compiled in C++ and `C++ stinks` when compiled in C.

**Explanation:**

> What causes the difference between languages is the `tr()` function. It takes advantage of one of the differences between C and C++, specifically, how char literals are treated. In C, they are treated as integers, so `sizeof('!')` returns 4, as opposed to 1 in C++. The `((...+1)&1)` part is just part of a simple bitwise operation that will return 1 if `sizeof('!')` returns 4, and 0 if it returns 1. That resulting number is multiplied by the ints in array `t` and then that product is finally added to the specific character being transformed. In C++ the product will always be zero, so the string `C++ rules!` remains unchanged. In C, the product will always be the value in `t`, and so the string changes to `C++ stinks`.

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe of something...

Comment: @BetaDecay Is it? I tried searching for something similar and I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Can you please explain how your program works differently (if it doesn't spoil the challenge)?

Comment: @A.L I edited in an explanation to my post.

Comment: All the ones from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038200/write-a-program-that-will-print-c-if-compiled-as-an-ansi-c-program-and-c/ could be used here - with a little obfuscation.

Answer (score 20):

## Is the cake a lie?

As there has been much debate over whether the cake is or is not a lie, I wrote this program to answer this contentious question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// checks if two things are equal
#define EQUALS(a,b) (sizeof(a)==sizeof(b)) 

struct Cake{int Pie;}; // the cake is a pie!
typedef struct Cake Lie;
main(){
    struct CakeBox{
        struct Cake{ // the cake contains lies!
            Lie Lies[2];
        };
    };
    typedef struct Cake Cake;

    printf("The cake is ");
    if(EQUALS(Cake, Lie)){
        printf("a LIE!\n");
    }else{
        printf("..not a lie?\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What will the outcome be?

C:

> `The cake is ..not a lie?`

C++:

> `The cake is a LIE!`

Comment: This. I like this.

Answer (score 10):

### Just some bools

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test(bool)
  {
  return sizeof(bool) == sizeof(int);
  }

int main(void)
  {
  puts(test(0) ? "C" : "C++");
  return 0;
  }
```

http://codepad.org/dPFou20W
http://codepad.org/Ko6K2JBH

Comment: bool is not part of C89

Comment: @malat Yep, and exactly this fact is used in this solution.
For c++ the function is
int test(bool /*unnamed boolean argument*/);
and for C it uses default int declaration wich means
int test(int bool);
so 'bool' is a name of integer variable.

Answer (score 7):

I could have done this with a 3 line program but then it would be obvious why it produces different results for C and C++.  So instead I started writing a bigger program with some stegonography which gets different results in C and C++...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct product
{
    int quantity;
    char name[20];
    char desc[80];
}; 

struct _customer
{
    char name[80];
    struct product *products;
} customer;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

struct shipment
{
    char tracking_number[40];
    int quantity;
    struct product { int model; int serial; } sku;
};

struct _supplier
{
    char name[80];
    struct shipment *shipments;
} supplier;

/* now read the command line and allocate all the space we need */

if(argc<5)
{
    printf("Usage: %s <supplier name> <# of shipments> <customer name> <# of products> ",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}

strcpy(supplier.name,argv[1]);
int shipments_size = atoi(argv[2])*sizeof(struct shipment);
printf("Allocating %d bytes for %s shipments\n", shipments_size,supplier.name);
supplier.shipments=(struct shipment *)malloc(shipments_size);

strcpy(customer.name,argv[3]);
int products_size = atoi(argv[4])*sizeof(struct product);
printf("Allocating %d bytes for %s products\n", products_size,customer.name);

/* ... TODO ... finish the rest of this program later */

free(customer.products);
free(supplier.shipments);

return 0;
}
```

You need to specify a command line.  When I run it on my copy of gcc I get this output:

```
>g++ x.cpp

>a.exe "Bob Supplier" 1 "Jane Customer" 1
Allocating 52 bytes for Bob Supplier shipments
Allocating 104 bytes for Jane Customer products

>gcc x.c

>a.exe "Bob Supplier" 1 "Jane Customer" 1
Allocating 52 bytes for Bob Supplier shipments
Allocating 8 bytes for Jane Customer products
```

How can things go so horribly wrong?

Comment: Although others did the same thing, you masked it pretty well.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int c[1]; 
int main() { 
   struct c { int cpp[2]; }; 
   printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(c)/4);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This one works with C++11 and newer and any C so far (before C11).

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    auto a = 'a';
    printf(sizeof(a) == sizeof(int) ? "C\n" : "C++\n");
    return 0;
}
```

See here:
C++: http://ideone.com/9Gkg75
and C: http://ideone.com/eECSmr

It exploits the fact that in C++11 the auto keyword got a new meaning. So while a in C is of type int stored in an AUTOmatic location it is of type char in C++11.

EDIT: As FUZxxl said the implicit int was removed in C11.

Comment: Doesn't work with C11 as C11 has removed the implicit `int` rule.

Comment: @FUZxxl Thanks, I adjusted my post.

Answer (score 1):

## Self-describing program

This will print "This program is written in C!" if compiled using a C compiler; otherwise, it'll print "This program is written in C++!". It needs a C99 compiler.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
char str[] = "This program is written in C++ ";
#define S (sizeof(str)-sizeof(true)-sizeof(true)%4)
int main(){for(int i=S;i<=S+1;++i)str[i]=i==S?'!':'\0';puts(str);return 0;}
```

> Most other posts take advantage of the difference of the size of a char in C vs C++; this one uses the fact that, in C99, `true` is defined to be a number. This inserts the exclamation point and null terminator based on the size of `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char arr[100];
  printf("%zu",sizeof(0, arr)); // prints 8 in C and 100 in C++
}
```

In C the comma operator forces an [array-to-pointer conversion](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) while in C++ the [result of the comma operator](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.comma#1):

> The type and value of the result are the type and value of the right operand; the result is of the same value category as its right operand,